# I am unable to a inserting the content HTML pre tag

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

```
Function objective()
{
    Document.getelementbyid("pre").innerhtml=""
}
```

And in the HTML for my `li` in nave, I declared the `onclick` function but it is not working.

> Note:- I am clear about case sensitivity in js and using bootstrap3
>   for resposive.

Comment: put proper code so we will try to solve

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.getElementsByTagName` instead. This will return an array of all the elements that have that tag name.

Due to it returning an array, you need to make sure you use `[0]` to find the first index in the array.

```js
function objective(){
  document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].innerHTML="";
}
objective();
```

```html
<pre>This is some content that will not show in the snippet</pre>
<div>This content will though</div>
```

Comment: Actually I am thinking to do is when I claikc my nav iteam then it have to print some text and the content in the pre tag have to be changed from one li element to another.

Answer (score 0):

getelementbyid() expect a id, not a tag name,your code will call on html like

```
<pre id="pre">

</pre>
```

if you want to select elementnot by id but form tag name use `document.querySelectorAll("pre")[0]` or `document.querySelector("pre")`

remember querySelectorAll return an array!!

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` selects an `element` with defined `id` as in your case `pre` as an `id`.

You must have an `id` attached to your `element` same that of `argument` in `getElementById()`.

Or, you can use `getElementsByTagName` which selects `element` given in `argument`.